# background image color change ie8

Tags: image, internet-explorer-8

I added a background image on my page but IE8 is changing color of my image. My image is jpg not png so I do not think it IE should have any issue of pngcrush. What should I do for removing this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please paste add your css.

Comment: yes, here is my css applied on div 
[code]
.topdiv{
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url('/image/technology--bgimage');
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='/image/technology--bgimage', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: :;
float: left;
width: 100%;}
[code]

Comment: Please create a fiddle. So that it will be easy.

Comment: @shimer - please always edit the question to include the code rather than pasting it into a comment -- code is practically unreadable in SO comments.

Comment: @Spudley sorry I am new at stackoverflow and did not know how to add code

Comment: @shimer: no worries, we're all new once :-). Click the 'edit' link at the foot of the question, and paste the code there. Make sure to indent it by four spaces, as this will trigger the site to format it as code rather than plain text.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yevZt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have `'/image/technology--bgimage'`
try adding the file type and see what happens:

```
'/image/technology--bgimage.jpg'
```